# Fully connected layer for each channel individually in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to apply a **different** dense layer to each channel of the input?
I.e. having a input tensor of `[batch,height,width,channels]` I would like to apply a different dense layer to each channel, thus having `#channels` layers, each with a input of `height*width`.
From tensorflow dense docs I see that

```
Note: that if inputs have a rank greater than 2, then inputs is flattened prior to the initial matrix multiply by weights.
```

which is not the desired outcome in this situation.

Comment: Are you planning to unify those layers again at a later point? And do the channels share any form of mutual information?

Comment: No, I want to stack several "separated" FC  until I have 1 number per kernel

Comment: Why don't you then define separate networks and feed the channels separately to those?